# Another efcore violation of primary key constraint reference table problem

Tags: database, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

Assume I've read and googled, and I still don't know what I'm doing incorrectly.  Whenever I try to execute

```
_dbContext.Set<T>().Add(aMediaObjectWithAssociatedProvider);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I get the dreaded efcore violation of primary key constraint reference table

I have a class as such:

```
public class Media : BaseModel
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual string? Description { get; set; }

    public virtual string Source { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid? MediaTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid? ProviderId { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Provider? Provider { get; set; }

}
```

The BaseModel class is

```
public abstract class BaseModel : IBaseModel
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

The Provider class is as such:

```
public class Provider : BaseModel
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string? ApiUsername { get; set; }

    public virtual string? ConfigurationSection{ get; set; }
}
```

My DBContext has the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
{            
    mb.Entity<Media>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
    mb.Entity<Media>().HasOne(p => p.Provider).WithOne().HasForeignKey<Media>(x => x.ProviderId);
}
```

The code for inserting a new object is as follows:

```
public T Insert(T oneObject)
    {

        try
        {
            // Ensure the entity has an ID
            if (oneObject.Id == Guid.Empty)
            {
                oneObject.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            }

            _dbContext.Set<T>().Add(oneObject);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            _logger.LogError(error.Message, error);
        }

        return oneObject;
    }
```

Assume that providers are static, in a sense that they already exist in their table, and I don't want to add new providers when I save media... Media just needs to have a provider.

I know exactly what is happening (the model, after travelling through json back through the api to the server is losing context, but I'm also trying to build a repository type of system where I don't have to build complex save logic for every object. (hence why i'm hand wringing over adding code that loads existing providers).

***This problem specifically began rearing its head when I was saving new Media objects into the database with existing Providers.  I am still mulling over how to look up children dynamically, but i'm not quite there yet.***

I've been at this for so long, i'm about ready to give up on efcore relations and just rebuild the models as single objects, and handle all of the manipulation in javascript.  And I don't like this idea.

I know for a fact that there will be questions for more code, but please let me know what.  Again, I'm just stepping into .net core / ef core so this code-first is a little confusing for me.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may have 2 options to try. Do backup your whole project and database beforehand. Clone your database to another database name. Try these either one option using new cloned database for testing.

### No.1

Set "newid()" without quotes in your ID's default value in sql server. So you don't need to use Guid.NewGuid() in code every insert. newid() will auto generate GUID.

[image]

### No. 2

How about removing primary key from ID (GUID) and then creating new column "UID" (running number) and set UID (running number) as primary key and enable its identity? You need to change all other tables too. And re-link UID each other if you use relationship. This way, your UID will not have existing number when insert.